# declaration of entities for connection TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I try many things to import entities into a create connection TypeORM in my script but nothing run correctly. That way I have nothing ready repository for working with my entities into my code.

**the file dealing with TypeORM library :**

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'
import {Public} from './../entity/Public'

export default class ConnectionManager
{
    async createConnection()
    {
        this.connection = await this.connectionManager.create({
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            synchronize: true,
            entities: [
                Public,
                './../entity/Public.js',
                './../entity/Public.ts',
                './../entity/Public',
                './../entity/*.js',
                './../entity/*.ts',
                "./../entity/Public.js",
                "./../entity/Public.ts",
                "./../entity/Public",
                "./../entity/*.js",
                "./../entity/*.ts",
                "src/entity/*.ts",
                "src/entity/*.js",
                'src/entity/*.ts',
                'src/entity/*.js',
            ],
        })
    }
```

- The Public file seems to be correctly imported into script
- The connection seems to be correctly created (but without entities)

*Why and how to correctly declare entities into connection creation for TypeORM ?*

Answer (score 0):

Entities is seemed to be not created in recent version of typeorm. So kindly use the below command to generate the Entities Using "typeorm-model-generator" package.

```
npx typeorm-model-generator -d "Database path or Host" -e DatabaseName -o "Path of Entity folder"
```

this will help you to generate the Entity schema.
Thank You.

Comment: Issue seems to be in other way. But you response is interested for helping to work with typeORM. THX.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an index.ts file in ./../entity/ and import all your entities class in like that:

```
import {Public1} from "./public1";
import {Public2} from "./public2";

export default [
   Public1,
   Public2
]
```

and import in the file where you create connection like that:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm';
import entities from './../entity';

export default class ConnectionManager
{
    async createConnection()
    {
        this.connection = await this.connectionManager.create({
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: './src/data/mydb.sql',
            synchronize: true,
            entities,
        })
    }
```

It will be better to read and to organize.